# How to merge to indexed arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, merge

I have the following object:

```
object1 = [
 { title: "id", platformOne: value},
 { title: "name", platformOne: name }, 
 { title: "env", platformOne: env }
]
```

I want to merge it with this other one. Same structure, same "title" key, but a different key name just following that:

```
object2 = [
 { title: "id", platformTwo: value},
 { title: "name", platformTwo: name }, 
 { title: "env", platformTwo: env }
]
```

I want it to look like this:

```
object3 = [
 { title: "id", platformOne: value, platformTwo: value},
 { title: "name", platformOne: name, platformTwo: name }, 
 { title: "env", platformOne: env, platformTwo: env }
]
```

Could you please help me with this? Much appreciated.

Comment: Please post an attempt. Hint: try `Array#map` if the arrays are the same length.

Comment: You seem to be looking for `zipWith`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
const object3 = object1.map((obj, idx) => ({...obj, ...object2[idx]}));
```

Comment: You are missing one parentheses at the end
object1.map((obj, idx) => ({...obj, ...object2[idx]}));

Comment: Yeah.. sorry, now is fixed

Comment: This is elegant and perfect. Exactly what I was looking for in a single line. Thank you very much indeed!

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways to do this one of them you using `reduce`

```js
object1 = [
  { title: "id", platformOne: "value" },
  { title: "name", platformOne: "name" },
  { title: "env", platformOne: "env" },
];

object2 = [
  { title: "id", platformTwo: "value" },
  { title: "name", platformTwo: "name" },
  { title: "env", platformTwo: "env" },
];
arr = [object1, object2].flat();
res = arr.reduce((r, o) => {
  if (!r[o.title]) r[o.title] = o;
  else r[o.title] = { ...r[o.title], ...o };
  return r;
}, {});
console.log(Object.values(res));
```

if you want to simplify the code above you could use the ternary operator

```js
object1 = [ { title: "id", platformOne: "value" }, { title: "name", platformOne: "name" }, { title: "env", platformOne: "env" }, ];
object2 = [ { title: "id", platformTwo: "value" }, { title: "name", platformTwo: "name" }, { title: "env", platformTwo: "env" }, ];
arr = [object1, object2].flat();
res = arr.reduce(
  (r, o) => (
    !r[o.title] ? (r[o.title] = o) : (r[o.title] = { ...r[o.title], ...o }), r
  ),
  {}
);
console.log(Object.values(res));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as well :

```js
var object3 = [];

object1.forEach(function(item, index){ 
object3[index] = item; 
object3[index].platformTwo = object2[index].platformTwo;
});
```